# React-Native - com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I was working on my react native dynamic links feature.

I have tried the following code for creating links :

```
const generatedDynamicLink = await firebase.dynamicLinks().buildLink({
            link: `https://test.page.link/groupinvite/name=test`,
            domainUriPrefix: `https://test.page.link/groupinvite`,
            android: {
                packageName: 'com.test',
            },
            ios: {
                bundleId: 'com.test',
                appStoreId: '1546898245',
            },
        });
```

Above method works perfectly.

But, it gives me a long link like,
https://test.page.link//guestinvite?apn=com.test&ibi=com.test&isi=1498742044&link=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.page.link/%2Fguestinvite%2Fname%3Dtest

So to shorten the link i'm replacing firebase.dynamicLinks().buildLink(....) with "firebase.dynamicLinks().shortLink({.....},"SHORT")" But it gives me an error like,

Error: [dynamicLinks/build-failed] com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link:

So can anybody please suggest me a workaround solution to create a short link like "com.test/guestinvite/abdgsyd" ?

Also, how to easily fetch the initial link.

Currently i am using following link but i'm not able to get query parameter "name" from link.

```
componentDidMount() {
    dynamicLinks().getInitialLink().then((initialLink)=>{
    console.log('initialLink : ', initialLink.url);
    });
  }
```

I am using following dependencies :

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.3.4",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^6.3.4",
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/a5847c983761f71fef71f54ac4d9e682942941b0/docs/dynamic-links/quick-start.md) tutorial, they made with:

```js
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
  link: 'https://invertase.io',
  domainUriPrefix: 'https://xyz.page.link',
  analytics: {
    campaign: 'banner',
  }
});
```

In your case, it would be:

```js
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

const generatedDynamicLink = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
  link: `https://test.page.link/groupinvite/name=test`,
  domainUriPrefix: `https://test.page.link/groupinvite`,
  android: {
      packageName: 'com.test',
  },
  ios: {
      bundleId: 'com.test',
      appStoreId: '1546898245',
  }
});
```

I dont know if this is going to work, but i hope so.